# How to show time away from computer?

Tags: arch-linux, screensaver, kde4, screen-lock

I was wondering how to measure the time elapsed after, say, screensaver starts and then show that time on a freedesktop notification when back.

Comment: The `xprintidle` command gives you the idle time in milliseconds for the corresponding display

Comment: At least in my archlinux KDE4 system the command is not available if not installed from AUR, I'm looking for something more native if possible

Comment: There's also `xssstate -i` from http://www.suckless.org

Comment: @NicoRodsevich What do you mean by "more native"? "In official Arch repos" doesn't necessarily equate to "more native".

Comment: @Sparhawk I mean something that is common to most GNU/Linux distros, that comes from the very beginning, with the install of the system

Comment: @NicoRodsevich Playing the Devil's Advocate, a basic Arch install is pretty minimal…

Answer (score 0):

Add the following lines to your XResources file

```
~/.Xresources
xscreensaver.logFile:/var/log/xscreensaver.log
xscreensaver.verbose:true
```

This is if xcreensaver is your screensaver, you can replace it with your favorite screensaver utility.

You can then grep the log file.

Comment: Sorry I didn't comment before, didn't have the reputation to do so.
I don't have that file in ~, only .Xdefaults and .Xauthority

Comment: You can create the file, I think Xdefaults also works.